# Normalized and immutable data model

Tags: scala, haskell, normalization, immutability, database-normalization

How does Haskell solve the "normalized immutable data structure" problem?

For example, let's consider a data structure representing ex girlfriends/boyfriends:

```hs
data Man = Man {name ::String, exes::[Woman]}

data Woman = Woman {name :: String, exes::[Man]}
```

What happens if a Woman changes her name and she had been with 13 man? Then all the 13 man should be "updated" (in the Haskell sense) too? Some kind of normalization is needed to avoid these "updates".

This is a very simple example, but imagine a model with 20 entities, and arbitrary relationships between them, what to do then?

What is the recommended way to represent complex, normalized data in an immutable language?

For example, a Scala solution can be found [here](https://github.com/suzaku-io/diode/blob/0e443dec08313ff4cc81fcbab71eb31a8dce6632/doc/usage/ApplicationModel.md) (see code below), and it uses references. What to do in Haskell?

```
class RefTo[V](val target: ModelRO[V], val updated: V => AnyRef) {
  def apply() = target()
}
```

I wonder, if more general solutions like the one above (in Scala) don't work in Haskell or they are not necessary? If they don't work, then why not? I tried to search for libraries that do this in Haskell but they don't seem to exist.

In other words, if I want to model a normalized SQL database in Haskell (for example to be used with [acid-state](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/acid-state)) is there a general way to describe foreign keys? By general I mean, not hand coding the IDs as suggested by chepner in the comments below.

EDIT:

Yet in other words, is there a library (for Haskell or Scala) that implements an SQL/relational database in memory (possibly also using Event Sourcing for persistence) such that the database is immutable and most of the SQL operations (query/join/insert/delete/etc.) are implemented and are type-safe ? If there is not such a library, why not ? It seems to be a pretty good idea. How should I create such a library ?

EDIT 2:

Some related links:

- https://realm.io/news/slug-peter-livesey-managing-consistency-immutable-models/
- https://tonyhb.gitbooks.io/redux-without-profanity/content/normalizer.html
- https://github.com/agentm/project-m36
- https://github.com/scalapenos/stamina
- http://www.haskellforall.com/2014/12/a-very-general-api-for-relational-joins.html

Comment: If you had normalized data, wouldn't you have `data Man = Man {name :: String, exes :: [WomanID]}`, where `womanID` was an index into a data structure story `Woman` values (something like `Map WomanID Woman`? If you change the name of a `Woman` value, this doesn't affect any `Man` value referencing it; you need only update the single value in the `Map`.

Comment: Right, the given example is not normalized. The question is if there is a general solution for creating normalized data structures (something that takes care of the handling of the IDs etc) ? I mean, what do Haskellers do when they want to create normalized data ? Do they always hand code the IDs ? Or is there some more general solution for this problem already ? What you proposed is an example of Hand coding the IDs, but this could be automated I guess. I wonder what is the general solution for creating and resolving those IDs.

Comment: @jhegedus The question as it stands is a bit broad - it really depends on the situation. If you are constantly updating the the men and women, you may want to perform the computation in a state monad (the state being the table/map of men/women). If you are looking for a functional approach to more general graph structures, check out [`fgl`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fgl). With respect to IDs: there are some situations where you can [tie the knot](https://wiki.haskell.org/Tying_the_Knot) (sometimes even using the `Map`), but in general you may need to hand code IDs.

Comment: Interesting so solutions like this (see "References within the Model" section in the link below) are not working in Haskell ? http://ochrons.github.io/diode/usage/ApplicationModel.html

Comment: A table represents a(n application) relationship; a FK represents the fact that if a certain subtuple is in one relationship then it's in another. What does a "way to represent complex, normalized data in an immutable language" have to do with "a general way to describe foreign keys"? Also, why "immutable"? It would seem to be a red herring, since (as acknowledged but not explained by your quoting "update") the issue is not about state per se (indeed the issue of update anomalies can really only arise under *mutable* semantics) but about a certain minimizing of invalid data structure values.

Comment: The problem in mutable languages (such as `Java`) can be solved by object references. Because there I can just mutate the name of the Women with 13 exes. The object references point to the same `Women` whose name I mutate, so there is no need to mutate all the `Woman`'s names in all 13 `Men`'s list of exes. So solving the problem in mutable languages is different from solving it in immutable languages. In mutable languages I don't even notice this problem because using object references + mutation I can model a relational database without much thinking.

Comment: I just create an object graph and then mutate data in it. Just like in a DB. I cannot do the same thing in Haskell.

Comment: I think this is an excellent question and I'm sorry to see all the close votes. I think you would find this blog post series (on "Purely Functional Retrogames") illuminating: http://prog21.dadgum.com/23.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, I see how it connects to this question.

Comment: It's not *immutability* that is your difficulty. It's lack of an operator giving a value that looks like another value with a new part replacing an old part. Eg for a record type, there is such an operator for a part that is a field, and ' "update" ' is simple. Eg for a table of rows, many rows may change. Regardless of mutability. We walk a representation to update parts. Under  immutability *having* to clone but under mutability possibly cloning. "Normalization" is in a general sense restructuring to reduce that walking and the number of parts. Mutability vs immutability is not at issue.

Comment: Here is a related Reddit discussion : https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/5ovfvv/normaliezed_immutable_data_model_in_scala_how_to/

Answer (score 9):

The problem is you are storing data and relationships in the same type. To normalise, you need to separate. Relational databases 101.

```
newtype Id a = Id Int -- Type-safe ID.
data Person = Person { id :: Id Person, name :: String }
data Ex = Ex { personId :: Id Person, exId :: Id Person }
```

Now if a person changes their name, only a single `Person` value is affected. The `Ex` entries don't care about peoples' names.

Comment: Interesting point! It's a many to many relationship, indeed. What I was after however - as mentioned in the question as well - is "not hand coding the IDs as suggested by chepner in the comments below."  Some kind of a library that does what you suggested but takes away all the boilerplate and adds support for queries, joins and whatnot. Basically an SQL database but instead of using SQL as a query language it uses Haskell to describe things that can be described with SQL. Type safe and immutable.

Comment: @jhegedus here's the thing. You can't abstract away the foreign key; it's part of your domain semantics--i.e., it answers the question 'What makes a person in the relationship uniquely _that_ person?' No library can decide that for you.

Comment: So basically `Ex` corresponds to an SQL database table which needs to be explicitly specified. I get that but maybe SQL can be replaced by Haskell, fully type safe, immutable. Or not ? I wonder why that has not been done ?  (Not a binding to a database, but an actual in-memory database, written in Haskell). I am asking this because a friend is writing a (successful) app in Scala, and is doing exactly that because 1) no duplication of data (memory-database), 2) type safety 3) Scala is more expressive than SQL. So if it is worth to do that in Scala, why no Haskell lib. exists for that ? I wonder

Comment: @jhegedus not sure, I'm not being able to verify what the Scala code is doing--the link in your question is 404ing.

Comment: Just fixed the broken link. Btw, the app that I am referring to in my previous comment is not the one I am linking to, it is a commercial app, akin to Uber but smaller. This approach seems to be working for him very well, so I was wondering - if it is such a good approach - then why have I not seen any public library for it, not for Haskell, not for Scala. This was the original motivation for posting this question to SOF.

Comment: @jhegedus three things. (1) the `RefTo` type is still under the hood using some identifier as the base reference. Notice that you have to manually tell it how to get a product uniquely by ID. (2) I'm not convinced of the additional value brought by the Diode approach. Feels like I could have immutability with FRP (/streaming). (3) Haskell people _probably_ haven't acutely felt the need for a wrapper over identifier references, because of lenses and language-level niceties. It may be simpler to just do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Project [M63](https://github.com/agentm/project-m36) comes pretty [close](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/project-m36/iuHGohDNkzE) to what I was looking for. It is written in Haskell.

A more lightweight Haskell solution is outlined in Gabriel Gonzalez's post "[A very general API for relational joins](http://www.haskellforall.com/2014/12/a-very-general-api-for-relational-joins.html)".

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you would apply Project M63 specifically to the model you asked about? Also, the link with text 'close' seems to be to a message in your personal Gmail inbox. Gabriel Gonzalez' join technique is pretty damn cool though--but it still doesn't abstract away ID management 

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the link.

Comment: I don't know how to use M36, based on the description however it seems to be what I was looking for. Immutable relational database. It seems at the moment that there is no Scala equivalent (at least not a public one). Or maybe I just don't know about it ? It would be interesting to know if there is something like M36 for Scala.